# cannot execute cmd command with ruby

Tags: ruby, svn, cmd

I want to execute an svn command in windows cmd. It should be launched by ruby code. 
Here is my code.

```
svn = `svn log -r 120:125 %svn_repo%`
puts svn
```

Here, svn_repo is a windows environment variable. I get the following error when I run
the code:

```
svn: E155007: 'C:\Code\Ruby\%svn_repo%' is not a working copy
```

What is the error and how do i fix it ?

The same command works when I execute it directly in cmd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to your environment variables with `ENV`.

So this should work:

```
svn = `svn log -r 120:125 %s` % ENV['svn_repo']
puts svn
```

Alternative you can use:

```
svn = `svn log -r 120:125 #{ENV['svn_repo']}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming svn_repo is a local variable, try

```
svn = `svn log -r 120:125 #{svn_repo}`
puts svn
```

Comment: svn: E160013: '/svn/mycode/!svn/rvr/123/applications/trunk%0A' path not found
Looks like some characters are getting escaped. How to prevent this ? Thanks.